# How do I show dependency tree for a cabal project

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am using `cabal v2-build` to build a project and it keeps failing on a package that I do not directly depend on. Is there a way with `cabal` to list all of a package's dependencies (ideally in tree format) so I can see what I'm relying on that's calling the build fail and (hopefully) get rid of it.

Answer (score 7):

Try `cabal-plan`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-plan

In particular `cabal-plan info` will display copious information on dependencies in a tree format.

Note that `cabal-plan` requires that you've run `cabal` first, but the build need not complete successfully. It just needs to get past the build-plan stage. `cabal-plan` will then read the meta-info cabal created and display it in a readable format for you in detail.

(Aside: `cabal-plan` can also create transitive license info, quite useful as well. See the `license-report` option, which does require a separate flag during build time.)

Comment: Indeed `cabal-plan` only needs that the `cabal configure` step executed successfully, creating the meta-info in the `dist-newstyle` directory.

Answer (score 3):

`cabal-plan` does not seem to work for transitive dependencies.

You can use `cabal freeze` and look at the generated freeze file to see every single dependency that is required for the project.

(also, here's a useful tool for looking up reverse dependencies https://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse)

---

> `cabal freeze` writes out a freeze file which records all of the
> versions and flags that are picked by the solver under the current
> index and flags. Default name of this file is `cabal.project.freeze`  
> … …

https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.8/cabal-commands.html#cabal-freeze