# Generating Haskell module dependency tree

Tags: haskell

Is there a way I could generate (and view) the module dependency tree of my Haskell project? I've seen images of such graphs but am unable to dlfigure out how it could be done.

Comment: When use Haskell-stack, `stack dot --external`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I show dependency tree for a cabal project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61673348/how-do-i-show-dependency-tree-for-a-cabal-project)

Answer (score 4):

For Haskell stack, you can let `stack` write a GraphViz dot file for the dependency graph with:

```
stack dot --external
```

The `--external` flag means it will include dependencies not defined in your stack project. You can for example use I/O redirection to write it to a file with:

```
stack dot --external > deps.dot
```

and then use `dot` as a tool to convert this to an image, for example with:

```
dot -Tpng deps.dot -odeps.png
```

You can also make use of `-Tsvg`, `-Tgif`, etc. to pick another image format.

For more information, see the [*dependency visualization* section of the documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/dependency_visualization/).

Comment: This shows a graph of the external package dependencies, not a graph of the project's modules and their dependencies among one another.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a graph of a project's modules with [yav/graphmod](https://github.com/yav/graphmod):

```bash
cabal install graphmod
```

The in your project:

```bash
~/.cabal/bin/graphmod | dot -Tpng > modules.png
```

You can see more options with `~/.cabal/bin/graphmod --help`, change the output format with [options to `dot`](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/command.html#-T), and see [examples here](https://github.com/yav/graphmod/wiki).